# How to change Shipping & Handling charges to custom text on order email magento 2

Tags: order-email, magento2.3.0

We need to display the shipping amount to static text "TBD" To be decided.
 I have narrow down to this file `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Totals.php` Line no:124

```
if (!$source->getIsVirtual() && ((double)$source->getShippingAmount() || $source->getShippingDescription())) {
        $this->_totals['shipping'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'shipping',
                'field' => 'shipping_amount',
                //'value' => $this->getSource()->getShippingAmount(),
                'value' => 'TBD',
                'label' => __('Shipping & Handling'),
            ]
        );
    }
```

But this not work. can anyone have the Idea
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this file in your custom theme.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml

here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml

And update content like this ..

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
 * @see \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
 */
?>
<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total) : ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()) : ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false) ?>
    <?php else :?>
    <tr class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_code) ?>">
        <th <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getLabelProperties() ?> scope="row">
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()) : ?>
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel()) ?></strong>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel()) ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        </th>
        <?php if($_code == 'shipping'): ?>
            <td <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getValueProperties() ?> data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_total->getLabel()) ?>">
                <?php echo "TBD"; ?>
            </td>
        <?php else: ?>
            <td <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getValueProperties() ?> data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_total->getLabel()) ?>">
                <?php if ($_total->getStrong()) : ?>
                    <strong><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatValue($_total) ?>
                <?php endif?>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks Buddy, for appreciation!! :) Happy to help you.